# Upload profile photo at server from Mobile Gallery

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to upload profile photo at my web server as per game requirement.
For picking photo from device, I have used this plugin:
[Native Gallery for Android & iOS](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/native-gallery-for-android-ios-112630)

I have used this code to upload photo at web server but at present I can able to load photo within Image view component but can't able to upload at web server.

```
    IEnumerator PickImage (int maxSize)
{
    Texture2D texture = null;
    NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery (( path) => {
        Debug.Log ("Image path: " + path);
        if (path != null) {
            // Create Texture from selected image
            texture = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath (path, maxSize);
            if (texture == null) {
                Debug.Log ("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                return;
            }

            profileImage.sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0f, 0f, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f), 100f);
        }
    }, "Select an image", "image/*", maxSize);

    if (texture != null) {

        // make texture read and write able
        Texture2D readableTexture = DuplicateTexture(texture);
        Debug.Log ("readable texture width: " + readableTexture.width + " height: " + readableTexture.height);

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        Debug.Log ("player id: " + DataCollection.localPlayer.PlayerId);
        form.AddField (GameConstants.ARG_UPLOAD_PHOTO_PLAYER_ID, DataCollection.localPlayer.PlayerId);
        form.AddBinaryData (GameConstants.ARG_UPLOAD_PHOTO, readableTexture.GetRawTextureData (), "profilepic.jpg", "image/*");

        Dictionary<string,string> headerDisc = form.headers;

        WWW www = new WWW (GameConstants.API_UPLOAD_PHOTO, form.data, headerDisc);
        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null) {

            Debug.Log ("Data: " + www.text);
            profileImage.sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0f, 0f, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f), 100f);

        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Error: " + www.error);
        }

    }
    Debug.Log ("Permission result: " + permission);
}
```

Here is the debug output that I was getting:

[image]

There is some error running that I can't able to understand so please give me some help into this.

**EDIT:**
Button click event code, at here I have already reduced image size to web server compatible settings:

```
public void OnChangePhotoButtonClick ()
{
    // Don't attempt to pick media from Gallery/Photos if
    // another media pick operation is already in progress
    if (NativeGallery.IsMediaPickerBusy ())
        return;

    // Pick a PNG image from Gallery/Photos
    // If the selected image's width and/or height is greater than 512px, down-scale the image
    StartCoroutine (PickImage (256));
}
```

If I use RestClient or PostMan then in that image get uploaded properly.

[image]

Here is the server side code that used for fetching image:

[image]

Comment: What does the server-side code look like? The Log for the www.text says that "the photo has invalid image dimensions"

Comment: I have edited my question with more details, I have reduced texture to 256 pixels so that it become compatible with server size settings.